# Retroactive pattern and how events are replaced

Tags: java, events, design-patterns, event-handling

I am trying to get a working code up that uses Event Sourcing and Retroactive pattern as described by Martin Fowler.

I am a bit lost on how events are queued up ? since events are sent one by one to EventProcessor's process and reverse function . He says in his article that EventProcessor class will have access to the event queue.

but if my/his EventProcessor class looks like this

```
public class DomainEventProcessor {

    public void process(DomainEvent domainEvent) {

        if (domainEvent instanceof ReplacementEvent) {
            processReplacement((ReplacementEvent)domainEvent);
        } else {
            domainEvent.process();
        }
    }

    public void reverse(DomainEvent domainEvent) {
        domainEvent.reverse();
    }

    /*
    // replace the  event in event queue
     */
    private void processReplacement(ReplacementEvent e) {


    }
}
```

The domain event interface

```
public abstract class DomainEvent implements Serializable {

    public abstract void process();

    public abstract void reverse();
}
```

an example implementation event looks like this

```
public class BalanceUpdateEvent extends DomainEvent {

    private String subscriberId;

    private String balanceId;

    private Long delta;

    public String getSubscriberId() {
        return subscriberId;
    }

    public String getBalanceId() {
        return balanceId;
    }

    public Long getDelta() {
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
    // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void reverse() {
        SubscriberDomain subscriberDomain = SubscriberAggregate.getSubscriber(subscriberId);
        subscriberDomain.handleReverseEvent(this);
    }
}
```

Each event knows which domain object( which has state + business logic) can handle itself to make changes to domain object state.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DomainEventProcessor {

    private EventStore es;

    public DomainEventProcessor(EventStore es) {
        this.es = es;
    }

    public void replay(String aggregateId,Date after) {
        List<DomainEvent> events = es.loadEventStreamAfter(aggregateId,after);
        events.sort(Comparator.comparing(DomainEvent::getTimestamp));
        for(DomainEvent event : events) {
            if (event instanceof ReplacementEvent) {
                ReplacementEvent re = (ReplacementEvent)event;
                re.getReplacement().process();
            } else {
                event.process();
            }
        }
    }

    public void reverse(String aggregateId,Date after) {
        List<DomainEvent> events = es.loadEventStreamAfter(aggregateId,after);
        events.sort(Comparator.comparing(DomainEvent::getTimestamp).reversed());
        for(DomainEvent event : events) {
            if (event instanceof ReplacementEvent) {
                ReplacementEvent re = (ReplacementEvent)event;
                re.getOriginal().reverse();
            } else {
                event.reverse();
            }
        }
    }
}
```